# Tab competion in bash hangs at "select"

Tags: bash, tab-completion

Recently my tab completion in bash has become annoyingly slow. I enter part of a directory name and hit `Tab`, but it takes over a half second for the directory name to be completed. To debug, I ran strace on the shell process from another terminal while I ran the tab completion, and found that a call to "select" was taking up the time:

`06:06:35.379778 select(1, [0], NULL, [0], {0, 500000}) = 0 (Timeout)
06:06:35.881344 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0`

You can clearly see that the call to select times out after 500ms. I ran the same experiment in my local machine (this problem is happening on my company-provided VM) and observed that there is no call to `select` at all. My VM is running bash version `4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` and my local machine is running `4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

How can I debug this further? Should I just upgrade bash?

---

In response to Emily's comment:

```
~: complete
~: complete -r
~: echo $PROMPT_COMMAND

~: trap
trap -- '' SIGTSTP
trap -- '' SIGTTIN
trap -- '' SIGTTOU
```

Comment: Have you checked memory available at the problematic system?

Comment: Full: /dev/vda1                                                       147G  141G     0 100% /

Comment: why is that causing select to hang?

Comment: When you press tab all the file names in current directory are copied for matching/suggesting file/directory names. If you have no space or less space then this becomes slow or does not happen at all

Comment: strace shows that select is the problem, not the copying of filenames. I also cleared out some space in my VM (now there is 24 GB free) and the problem persists.

Comment: 1. `complete -r` and try again? 2. what's the `trap` output? 3. `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND`?

Comment: @EmilyE. updated my question

Comment: The call to `select()` is probably inside some library function. Trying to free up space before you investigate other details would seem like the way to go. I'm guessing `/tmp` is mounted on the partition which is full; maybe create a separate `/tmp` partition if you can.

Comment: do u still have the problem after `complete -r` and `trap - SIGTSTP SIGTTIN SIGTTOU`?

Comment: @tripleee /tmp is under /dev/vda1, which now has 50G of free space.

Comment: @EmilyE. yes, I still have the problem

Comment: What does `bind -psX|grep C-i` display?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Plenty of disk space, plenty of CPU and memory, but tab completion would regularly hang for 0.5 to 1.5 seconds. I ran strace and also saw the hang was at a pselect.

I fixed it by changing the `_tilde()` function in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash-completion` to always immediately return 0. It seems a comparison (`if [[ $1 == \~* && $1 != */* ]]; then ...`) is taking a long time to complete.

Adding a "`return 0`" at the beginning of the function made things go faster, and didn't seem to have any adverse effects.